# Cannot Answer a Question. System says I "need 10 points". I have 102

Tags: support

I cannot answer this question: [Is there an infinite amount of wavelengths of light? Is the EM spectrum continuous?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/169209/is-there-an-infinite-amount-of-wavelengths-of-light-is-the-em-spectrum-continuo)

There is no Answer button.  At the bottom of the question is this message:

> protected by Qmechanic♦ yesterday
>
> Thank you for your interest in this question. Because it has attracted low-quality answers, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site.
>
> Would you like to answer one of these unanswered questions instead?

However, I have 102 reputation points at this time.  I have not participated on physics.se yet; the points are awarded to me automatically due to my reputation on ell.se.

If it's due to a requirement to *earn* the points, wouldn't it be relevant to make *earned* explicit in the message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does minimum rep to answer protected question includes association points?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5424/)

Comment: [Mother Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170937/) on the association bonus and [another on](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210481) modifying the Protected text.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate since the message in the other one explicitly says *earned*; I wouldn't have asked had it said that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The banner you see is the one that appears when a question has been "protected". The requirement is that you have 10 rep that was *earned on this site*. That is, the association bonus is not counted toward that requirement.

Comment: Thank you everyone.  I think that the following rounds out the answer: The question [Improve “Protected Question” message with regard to rep gained through Association Bonus](http://bit.ly/1Exzm7O) addresses the issue of explicitly mentioning *earned* in the text. (Thanks for that @KyleKanos).